# Integrity error in django for null condition

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and trying to run simple application, currently I am getting data from 3rd party api and I try save that json into my db so below is my Model class.

```
class CollisionDetails(models.Model):

    crossStreetName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    onStreetName = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='')
    offStreetName = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='')
    numberOfPersonsInjured = models.IntegerField(default=0)



    def json_to_class(self, json_data, city):
        collision_detail = json_data #json.loads(json_data)

        self.crossStreetName = collision_detail.get('cross_street_name')
        self.onStreetName = collision_detail.get('on_street_name', 'Unspecified')
        self.offStreetName = collision_detail.get('off_street_name', 'Unspecified')
```

but when I am trying to save my object it is giving me integrity error saying

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'crossStreetName' cannot be null")
```

but I checked my db as well there is no not null condition I have kept, I am not sure why django is treating that as not null = True, is it default behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the default behaviour for Django Models is `null=False`,

As per the docs,

> null: If True, Django will store empty values as NULL in the database.
> Default is False.

You can read the official docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/

Comment: but I got one more field where I added **contributingFactorVehicle2 = models.CharField(default='Unspecified', max_length=50, null=True)** I am having same issue for that as well

Comment: @LowCool Have you run migrate commands after making the changes?

Comment: @LowCool thanks for accepting, would really appreciate an upvote if my answer helped.